# What are reasons to prefer an ingress over using `expose` in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes

If one uses `expose` in k8s then it is possible to assign an IP to an app so it could be accessed on the www.

It is also possible to configure an ingress. This is basically a rproxy.

What are reasons to use an ingress over `expose`?

Comment: With an ingress you can have multiples names on same port, no possible by exposing a port tied to only one service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Tensibai indicated:

> With an ingress you can have multiples names on same port, no possible
>   by exposing a port tied to only one service

Answer (score 0):

From a technical perspective, they are working in different tcp/ip layers.

Expose command create a layer 4 tcp/udp port redirection. While ingress works at layer 7, ingress can do alot more like ssl offlloading, distribute loads based on HTTP headers, cookies, or url etc

Comment: Perhaps you could explain when one could choose the first and in what situation the latter.